# How to get recyceview height after settings adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to get my recycle view height , I wrote this code but it doesn't work :

```
recyecle.getHeight()
```

and also this one

```
getLayoutParams().height
```

but both of them returns invalid height .

how can I get the exact height of recyceview?

Comment: (Single Item Height * number of items ) will give the exact height excluding Recycler Views's padding and Divider size.

Comment: Yeah, I think @ADM is right.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int getViewHeight(View view) {
    int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(screenWidth, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    view.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    return view.getMeasuredHeight();
  }
```

call this after the recyceview has layout
by add the layout listener or if you use this after onresume that will be ok too.
at least work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago. I got round it by setting a global layout listener, in my fragments onViewCreated method,  to pass through the height of the recycler to the adapter (and then to the view it was required in) when the layout was complete. Recycler views are difficult to get the height of because they are not included in the layout until the adapter is set.

```
view?.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            val height = main_recyclerview?.measuredHeight ?: 0
            if (height > 0) {
                view.viewTreeObserver?.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                mainAdapter.setRecyclerHeight(height)
            }
        }
    })
```

This is my code in kotlin, but it should give you some idea of what to do in Java

The remove layout listener is important as otherwise you can catch yourself in a loop of changing a layout property that causes a reset layout, that then calls your listener, which resets the property, etc, etc